# Element-wise substraction in Julia

Tags: arrays, matlab, julia, elementwise-operations

I am coming to julia from MATLAB and find myself startled at the idea that there isnt a better way to solve this: `1-[.5 .2 1]` in julia does not compute to `[0.5 0.8 0]`

`1-[.5 .2 1]` MATLAB-> `[0.5 0.8 0]`

While in julia the best I got is:

`-(-[.5 .2 1].+1)` julia-> `[0.5 0.8 0]`

What am I missing? Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `1 .- [.5 .2 1]` or `(1).-[.5 .2 1]` and have a look at [broadcasting](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/arrays/#Broadcasting). The dot operator gets mistaken for a floating point when written without space.

Comment: Bdw, Julia is not a Matlab clone, it doesn't aim to have the same identical syntax, although often it remains very close to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Andre Wildberg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9462095/andre-wildberg) said, use broadcasting:

```
1 .- [.5 .2 1] 

# 1×3 Matrix{Float64}:
# 0.5  0.8  0.0

# use commas to get a vector instead:
1 .-[.5, .2, 1]

# 3-element Vector{Float64}:
# 0.5
# 0.8
# 0.0
```

For more information about broadcasting, check the docs ([here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/mathematical-operations/#man-dot-operators) and [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/functions/#man-vectorized)).